# Regular expression (for php script)

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex to get from this:

```
<%image(20100213-na-de-les-mag-hij-even-blijven.jpg|120|120|)%>
```

to this:

20100213-na-de-les-mag-hij-even-blijven.jpg

Should be really simple but I'm kinda new to regex and been trying for over an hour now. I think the < and % and | are things that regex uses and I have to escape them?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that this is probably a homework assignment!

Comment: Probably not homework.. looks more like a scraper. Anyway, it's a trivial regular expression, but "What has been tried? How does it not work as expected?" [There is probably enough information here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to able to solve this problem on your own.

Comment: @user2864740 I guess it is homework because it is Dutch. Translated: He has to stay after class.

Comment: Looks like an ok question from a newbie? Why not just replace `<%image(` and `|120|120|)%>` with '' - easier code to write.

Comment: @GuyT That's presumably the name of the image (to display 120x120) taken/added 2010 or before, not a statement made by the OP.

Comment: If you're new to regex check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/3622940

Comment: You escape characters with `\\`

Comment: it also works http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/21

Comment: Thank you guys, and indeed I could just replace the <%image( but then the 120|120 is not always the same. ---> It's a custom migration from nucleus to wordpress.

Already done with it thanks to your help :)

Answer (score 1):

definely this one shall match :

`\(([^\|]+)\|`

with delimiters :

`/\(([^\|]+)\|/`

Comment: +1, but the last `|\` is not mandatory because you capture every thing that is not a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<%image\((.*)\|.*\|.*\|\)%>
```

You have to escape the characters `|`, `(` and `)`, you will be able to capture the stuff inside the parentheses `(.*)`. (Greedy)

http://regex101.com/r/eY6kM2/1

Or for a more lazy approach:

```
<%image\(([^\|]*?)\|.*\|.*\|\)%>
```

http://regex101.com/r/eY6kM2/2

Comment: I did on a website and it seemed to work, but now found it doesn't. Updating answer.